# How to put a value on datagridview checkbox?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My question is about.I have a datagridview in which i have fourth column as checkbox.

When clicking checkbox i want to get checkbox value in code behind. Can 
anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results when the checkbox value changes immediately, you'll need to implement a two step process.

First you'll need to generate the DataGridView's `CurrentCellDirtyStateChange` event,
 Check if the DataGridView's CurrentCell is both not `Nothing` and if the Index is 3 (since it is your fourth column), and finally commit the DataGridView.

Next you'll need to generate the DataGridView's `CellContentClick` event. You'd need to check if the `ColumnIndex` is 3 and if so then get the cell's value.

Here is an example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If e.RowIndex <> -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```